# Should shorthand tag links link to questions or wiki?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, markdown, hyperlinks

The editing help explains that one can link to tags with [shorthand links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags) such as `[tag:foo]`.

Currently such shorthand links to the relevant tag's questions page.  In many contexts, one wishes to direct the reader to the tag itself rather than the latest questions that have been asked on that tag; therefore would it not be more sensible for such shorthand to expand to a link to the tag's wiki/info page instead?

Failing that, could there be an extension to this shorthand notation to provide such a link—e.g. `[taginfo:foo]`?

Comment: The tag wiki excerpt is displayed above the questions, but I think it's easy to miss. It would be nice to have a shorthand way to get to the full tag wiki.